# Mercedes - What is this type of fuse?

Tags: mercedes-benz, fuse

The fuse in the picture seems to have a grounding cable:
[image: mercedes fuse]

What is it called and can I purchase from other than Mercedes retail e.g. eBay?

Note: I know it is housing a standard 15A fuse, but can I purchase the "jacket" with the cable from somewhere?

I am based in the UK.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a grounding cable. The black piece (with the red wire) into which the fuse is inserted is a "tap" - apparently some device is getting its power outside the normal wiring of the vehicle.

[image]

[Link to Amazon example of a tap](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011I9QZX2)

Comment: it's a handy way to add accessories in your vehicle ensuring that the original circuit is still protected and not overloaded, while providing for independent protection to the new circuit as well. Depending on the location of the tap, it will be switched (on with key) or unswitched (always on).

Comment: Ok. The reason for asking is because the fuse for the "cigarette lighter" at the front of the car is missing. A website showed this picture to replace the fuse. I can see there are other fuses in the fuse box with a similar cable which is attached to a screw in the body of the vehicle, hence my reasoning that it is a  "grounding" cable"